# How do fix ValueError: x and y must be the same size?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import pickle
from matplotlib import style

data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", sep=";")


data = data[["G1", "G3", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences", "freetime"]]

predict = "G3"

X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
Y = np.array(data[predict])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.1)

best = 0
for _ in range(3000):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1)

    linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()

    linear.fit(x_train, y_train)

    acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)
    print(acc)

    if acc > best:
        best = acc
        with open("studentmodel.pickle", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(linear, f)

pickle_in = open("studentmodel.pickle", "rb")
linear = pickle.load(pickle_in)

print('Co:  \n', linear.coef_)
print('Intercept:  \n', linear.intercept_)

predictions = linear.predict(x_test)
for x in range(len(predictions)):
    print(predictions[x], x_test[x], y_test[x])

p = 'G1'
style.use("ggplot")
pyplot.scatter(data[p],data["G3"])
pyplot.xlabel(p)
pyplot.ylabel("Final Grade")
pyplot.show()
```

**Error: raise ValueError ("X and y must be the same size")**
Can anyone please explain to me what I have done wrong? Because well I am new to programing and was following a tutorial and everything up to the last 5 lines was working fine but when I try to make a graph it gives me this error "raise ValueError ("X and y must be the same size")" it only allows me to make a graph if I write the code like this

```
style.use("ggplot")
pyplot.scatter(data["G3"],data["G3"])
pyplot.xlabel(p)
pyplot.ylabel("Final Grade")
pyplot.show()
```

Which only gives me a straight line on a graph

Thank you for any help!

Comment: No idea :o(.  Random thought: Have you tried changing `pyplot.scatter` to `pyplot.plot`?  Like `pyplot.plot(data[p], data['G3'], ls="none", marker='.', ms=12)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run following code using [this data.](https://github.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/blob/master/04_Apply/Students_Alcohol_Consumption/student-mat.csv)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pickle
from matplotlib import style

data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv")

# Here, I have changed columns because "G2" was occurring twice.
data = data[["G1", "G2", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences", "freetime"]]

predict = "G3"
print(data.head())
X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
print(X)
y = np.array(data[predict])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)

best = 0
for _ in range(3000):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)

    linear = LinearRegression()

    linear.fit(X_train, y_train)

    acc = linear.score(X_test, y_test)
    print(acc)

    if acc > best:
        best = acc
        with open("studentmodel.pickle", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(linear, f)

pickle_in = open("studentmodel.pickle", "rb")
linear = pickle.load(pickle_in)

print('Co:  \n', linear.coef_)
print('Intercept:  \n', linear.intercept_)

predictions = linear.predict(X_test)
for x in range(len(predictions)):
    print(predictions[x], X_test[x], y_test[x])

p = 'G1'
style.use("ggplot")
plt.scatter(data[p], data["G3"])
plt.xlabel(p)
plt.ylabel("Final Grade")
plt.show()
```

This will produce the following image.
[image]